# Insert saved signature in Pages.app

Tags: pages

Currently I export PDFs from Pages.app, open it in Preview.app and insert a previously saved signature. Is it possible to save a signature in Pages.app to insert it to documents later on?

Comment: The best solution to this issue might be to save a signature as a standalone PDF, then drag the PDF into a Pages document when required. This is essentially the way that PDFpen handles the problem, and I assume Preview does the same thing. The PDF applications just have a better way of keeping track of "library" images.

Comment: That’s an interesting idea. Do pdf files have size limitations? Like could a pdf be 20x50. px big?

Comment: I don't know of any size limitations. If they exist, they're much smaller and/or much larger than anything I've ever encountered. My signature file is a vector image (179x32) I created by tracing over my scanned signature using [Affinity Designer](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/designer/) ([Inkscape](https://inkscape.org) or [Illustrator](https://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html) would work just as well). If you already have a scanned image, just crop it down using Preview.app and export as PDF (or PNG, if you want a raster file).

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any solution for a similar shortcut, and I ended using:

1. "Capture screen" any white and small space from the screen.
2. Open the "Captured picture" with the Preview app.
3. Add your signature to the "Captured picture".
4. Add the "Captured picture" with your signature to the page document.

Here is a video about the short trick:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSEQeQ-8kNI

Comment: thx dude, you are genius